# How to recover from network error when running a large Teradata query?

Tags: jdbc, teradata

I have a java job that runs a query on Teradata and pushes the results to a local database. It's a large query (>80M records) and can take hours to finish (The slowness is not due to Teradata, but the local DB). Because it takes so long, there is a chance that it gets interrupted by a network error or something. When that happens I get this exception:

org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.ResultSetException: Unable to advance result set

If the failure occurs a few hours into the query then it cannot rerun the query because the job needs to deliver the result before a specific time every day. Is there a way to resume the query after such failure? I'm not sure if pagination is a good option because the query involves joining a few tables and the tables are updated frequently.

Comment: Are you using JDBC FastExport or traditional result set processing? How did you define the ResultSet (i.e. Foward Only, Scroll Insensitive)?

Comment: I'm not JDBC expert, so I simply call createQuery on the Handle returned from DBI.open(), then use Query.iterator() to fetch all results. I'm not setting any flags for Forward Only or Scroll Insensitive.